# Oracle empty query / union with nothing

Tags: oracle

In a query generating function I have pretty much the following query template:

```
select id from sometable where id in
(__ union __ union __ union __)
```

Each `__` is a sub query. Under certain circumstances, one or more of these sub queries might be irrelevant. Now the immediate question is why use that constant template? Well, with the current design it's hard to change.

So my question is: is there a beautiful or standard way in Oracle SQL to return nothing? Everything I found refered to handling nulls, and my best solution so far is using something meaningless like `select * from dual where 1 is null` which of course makes this code even uglier.

Comment: No, there's no standard way to return nothing that would be significantly more beautiful than what you provided in the question.

Comment: Then I think we're going with a design change. :)

Comment: If you always select the same number of columns of the same type, you could create a function (lets call it `nothing()`) that returns zero records of suitable type and then use `select nothing() from dual`. I think, it's the shortest form possible.

Comment: If you're deciding and modifying what each subquery should do, can't you just exclude an irrelevant one completely?